# What are the significant differences between Swagger and OpenAPI?

Tags: swagger, openapi

Are there any significant differences between Swagger and OpenAPI?
What is better to use in conjunction with Python (Django)?

As I understand it in general, Swagger is a commercial product, and OpenAPI is an open-source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenAPI is the *specification*. Meanwhile Swagger is *tools* to implement the specification. Originally the specification was *Swagger specification* but it was donated to become a standard with more companies behind.

See [What Is the Difference Between Swagger and OpenAPI?](https://swagger.io/blog/api-strategy/difference-between-swagger-and-openapi/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, sorry I cannot upvote I don't have enough points yet.

Comment: This is a useful explanation too: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/web-api-help-pages-using-swagger?view=aspnetcore-5.0